# How to place user-defined literal inside constexpr class of same type in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, syntactic-sugar, user-defined-literals

I want to implement my own string-literal class `Literal` and operator:

```
constexpr Literal operator""_s(const char* str, size_t size);

class Literal {
  friend constexpr Literal operator"" _s(const char*, size_t);

  constexpr Literal(const char* str, size_t size);

  const char* str = nullptr;
  const size_t size = 0u;
};
```

Then I want to place an empty literal inside my class:

```
class Literal {
  …
  static constexpr const Literal empty = ""_s;
  …
};
```

As expected compiler refuses such construction because class is incomplete at this point. Also I suggest that it's technically should be possible, since the compiler just needs to put somewhere the pair of `char* str = nullptr` and `size_t size = 0` for the `empty` literal and assign it at compile-time to the static instance of my class.

Is there some "trick" to achieve the clause like: `auto new_literal = Literal::empty;` ?

Comment: You need to use `inline` before `static constexpr const...`, then it compiles (in C++17)

Comment: Well, you could add a defaulted constructor and then just declare `Literal new_literal;`

Comment: @Aganju Umm no. `empty` is already implicitly `inline`, so writing it explicitly isn't going to help.

Comment: if you say so... works fore me, MSVC 15.7. I read that deep in some C++17 manual, this allows to use incomplete classes.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some "trick" to achieve the clause like: `auto new_literal = Literal::empty;`?

You can add a static member function,

```
class Literal {
  // …
  static constexpr Literal empty() { return ""_s; }
  // …
}
```

, and use it like

```
constexpr auto new_literal = Literal::empty();
```

However, note that

```
static_assert("" != nullptr);
static_assert(""[0] == '\0');
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such trick. This example is no different from

```
struct X;
constexpr X getx();

struct X {
    static constexpr X x = getx();

};
```

Incomplete classes can't be used as constexpr variables, as, per standard,

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the
>   object as const. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be
>   initialized.

At this point, compiler doesn't even know if the type is a literal type, so it can't accept incomplete class.